# Access foreign key objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
class Param(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name="param")
    height = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

1. I want is to annotate item with average price, but only keep params with height > 60.

   ```
   items = Item.objects.filter(param__height__gt=60).annotate(price=Avg('param__price'))
   ```
2. That's where I have problems. I want to fetch filtered Param objects from above query.
   Is it possible to do?
   I know that there is workaround:

   ```
   for item in items:
       item.params = item.param.filter(height__gt=60)
   ```

But there are a lot of additional queries.
So, my question whether can I access filtered param objects from items?

Comment: [I have answered the question over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755225/foreign-key-access/42756842#42756842) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
items = Item.objects.select_related('param').filter(param__height__gt=60).annotate(price=Avg('param__price')).all()
```

Comment: I need to fetch with height>60, not price. And after this I don't know how to get param objects, that satisfy ">60" requirement

Comment: You edited your question with my answer, doesn't the query work? what is the exact problem?

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote in my question. How to access for each item, filtered parameters?

Comment: You question is not clear, you mean that you want to pass the height parameter into another function? Are you looking for a lazy load? I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I want for each item to find average of price with height>60. Then for each item I want to fetch parameters objects with height>60.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45837/discussion-between-andrew-fount-and-petkostas)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Artist():
    blah = models.TextField()


class Album()
    blah = models.ForeignKey(blah)
```

the key is to be shaed in the class like this^

Also for example the key can be x,y points, time, user, or whatever you want!

https://github.com/Ry10p/django-Plugis/blob/master/courses/models.py
example line 52

-Cheers

Comment: Line 52 for more help https://github.com/Ry10p/django-Plugis/blob/master/courses/models.py