# Foreign Key Access

Tags: python, django, django-models

--------------------------------------------MODELS.PY--------------------------------------------

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("artist", max_length=50) #will display "artist" in front of artist-name
    year_formed = models.PositiveIntegerField()

#   Initialization Example
#     newArtist = Artist(name = 'Artist Name', year_formed = 2015);
#     newArtist.save();




# Album will be a foreign key
# Many to 1 relation ie (Single artist -> many albums)
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("album", max_length=50) #will display "album" in front of album-name
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
```

-----------------------------SHELL--------------------------------

```
newArtist = Artist(name = 'GBA',year_formed = 1990)
newArtist.save()
album1 = Album(name = 'a',artist = newArtist)
album2 = Album(name = 'b',artist = newArtist)
album3 = Album(name = 'c',artist = newArtist)
album1.save()
album2.save()
album3.save()
allAlbums = Album.objects.all()

for e in allAlbums:
    print(e.artist.name)
```

--------------------#Results in error-------------------------

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 170, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'Album' object has no attribute '_artist_cache'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 179, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 385, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DB_start.models.DoesNotExist: Artist matching query does not exist.
```

I am following the correct syntax as documentation yet results in error. How can I successfully access the foreign key fields? Have tried print (e__name) as well.

Comment: Can anyone who down votes at least explain why..

Comment: I am not the downvoter, neither do i know why you were downvoted, but What is the error you get in the shell ?

Comment: what do you get when you dump `allAlbums`. Can you add that?

Comment: funny thing is I replicated this and got the results. No errors.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the placement of the key you have set up.

```
class Artist():
    blah = models.TextField()


class Album()
    blah = models.ForeignKey(blah)
```

This is how the database will work

-Cheers

https://github.com/Ry10p/django-Plugis/blob/master/courses/models.py

52 line

Comment: Are you saying to switch them around?

Comment: the key is to be inside of the class not the class itself

Comment: match the key inside of a class like https://github.com/Ry10p/django-Plugis/blob/master/courses/models.py   LOOK at the line 52